# How to get the LIST URL using XSL for SharePoint Content Query Web Part?

Tags: xslt, sharepoint

How do I get the List URL (source list) for SharePoint Content Query Web Part?

I want something like xsl:variable below:

```
<xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
   <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
      <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

but return me the source list URL (No hard coded the URL method please, so it can be reusable), is it possible? So I can place in:

```
<a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}">Stack here</a>
```

Comment: I am not exactly familiar with Sharepoint. Is this an XSLT question? If it is, please provide a source XML and an exact description of the result you expect.